# Auto generating a value during update

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using ef-core 2.1 with MSSQL, in `OnModelCreating` I use the following which auto populates a created field correctly:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyModel>()
    .Property(e => e.Created)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .Metadata.AfterSaveBehavior = PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore;
```

Additionally, I want to populate (and update thereafter) another field as follows:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyModel>()
    .Property(e => e.Modified)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
    .ValueGeneratedOnUpdate()
    .Metadata.ValueGenerated = ValueGenerated.OnUpdate;
```

However, this has no effect. In reading [value-generated-on-add-or-update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add-or-update) it is not clear to me if no facility exists to support this and a trigger is the only option or I simply have the configuration wrong.

The fluent method calls appear to support this, anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I am not real familiar with what you are trying with `.Metadata.ValueGenerated`, however, I am doing something very similar in [my project](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/master/src/FilterLists.Data/EntityTypeConfigurations/BaseEntityTypeConfiguration.cs) with success (note that my db is MySQL).

Maybe try like below.

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<MyModel>()
    .Property(e => e.Modified)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

Comment: Hi Collin, the problem with OnAddOrUpdate is the column also gets a value on add. However it does not receive one on update. I suspect this is a database specific implementation issue and I am stuck performing the change in code.

Comment: What database are you using? Also, are you saying that with your current code, the value successfully gets set on add but not on update (and you want it set in both cases)?

Comment: Missed that, I am using MSSQL. With my code above, Modified never receives a value (with or without the meta data constraint). With your code, it only gets an initial value and never after during updates.

Comment: Hmm, mmk, looks like MS might suggest [setting up a trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#value-generated-on-add-or-update) which seems more complex than it needs to be. But, haven't tried with MSSQL. Sorry. Good, luck.